# Multiple search in list

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, model-view-controller

i am trying to search a list with multiple parameter but the parameters i enter are returning an empty list

```
public ActionResult Index(string accountNo, string bookingDate, string productType)
        {
            DataModel db = new DataModel();
            var kIRDates = from m in db.KIRDates
                           where m.Verbund.ToString() == accountNo.ToString() || accountNo.ToString() == null || accountNo.ToString() == ""
                           where m.Belegdatum.ToString() == bookingDate.ToString() || bookingDate.ToString() == null || bookingDate.ToString() == ""

                           where m.Sparte == productType || productType == null || productType == ""
                           select m;
            Session["kIRDates"] = kIRDates.ToList<KIRDate>();
            return View(kIRDates);
        }
```

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "KIRData", FormMethod.Get))
{

    @Html.TextBox("accountNo")
    @Html.TextBox("bookingDate")
    @Html.TextBox("productType")
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Its difficult to tell what you're looking for based on the amount of detail in your question, but you could try the code below.

```
    public ActionResult Index(string accountNo, string bookingDate, string productType)
    {
        DataModel db = new DataModel();
        var kIRDates = db.KIRDates.Where(m => m.Verbund.ToString() == accountNo || m.Belegdatum.ToString() == bookingDate || m.Sparte.ToString() == productType);

        Session["kIRDates"] = kIRDates.ToList<KIRDate>();
        return View(kIRDates);
    }
```